BrowserStack QA query - Is it possible to click in two places at once on one device?
A bit of context, I'm a QA and the role I work in currently requires us to check if two buttons can be tapped on at the same time. Web based, through a variety of browsers. E.g: our content has a two settings buttons on the screen that could in theory be tapped at the same time, which would be a pretty big bug.
At present we're trying to figure out if BrowserStack is suitable as a replacement for the physical devices we test on.
Does anyone know of a way to simulate clicking in two places at once on the same page, within the same browser?
There's not a way to select elements on the page either, as the whole page is part of a framework and subsequently, selects the whole frame as one, rather than allowing us to check the individual parts.
I've not been able to find anything about this in searching for anyone else trying the same thing. I'm really not sure it's possible or even usually a use case for others.

Does your client use 2 mouses parallel? Have you ever used 2 mouses parallel?
